# Gitlab(8.6.5) and Jenkins Merge Request Builder Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gitlab

After updating Gitlab CE to version 8.6.5 the merge request builder plugin (https://github.com/timols/jenkins-gitlab-merge-request-builder-plugin) stopped working on jenkins jobs for the merge requests I've created.

I have looked for this on around the internet but couldn't find something similar, is anyone else having the same problem?

Comment: Actually there are two plugins. "Gitlab-plugin" and "gitlab-merge-request-builder" (gitlab-merge-request-jenkins) plugin. So Gitlab-plugin seems to be EOL and it supports only freestyle and pipeline jobs. But the second one was released on 2015. So it's up to you what plugin do you like to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our team tried restarting Jenkins and it fixed this for us. There was an issue when our system administrator updated Gitlab and it crashed, so the two machines weren't in sync. Try the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to point out that it looks like this plugin is EOL https://github.com/timols/jenkins-gitlab-merge-request-builder-plugin/issues/181